# Make Text Look Normal in Mode 13h(X86 Assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm using X86 Assembly to make an operating system with a GUI instead of just text. So I set the video mode to 13h(320x200,256 colors) so I can draw dialogs and sorts. But when I want to print text, it comes out all big and pixel-like. Is there any way to print text at a resolution similar to that of text video modes(0-3) when using a graphics mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to print text at a resolution similar to that of text video modes(0-3) when using a graphics mode?

The only way is to use a high resolution graphic mode. VGA 80x25 text corresponds to a 720x400 pixel mode.

Comment: Do you know what modes are like that(0 to 19)?

Answer (score 1):

Basically no. If you really have to use the Mode 13h, you could use antialiased fonts on the other hand there are other modes but not as compatible as the 13h that would give you 640x400x256 or even higher, look for the VESA standard for higher resolutions.